# Magento Quote Item object - how can I load item's options?

Tags: php, magento

While I know that I can just load Quote Item Options collection and filter it by item_id, I just can't wrap my mind around that Magento folks haven't added any `_afterLoad` or `_loadOptions` method to easily assign the options to an item, since there's already a `_options`, `_optionsByCode` properties...

to provide some example of what I'm doing:

```
// updated (forgot to actually load object
$item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($itemId);
$buyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest(); // almost empty, only qty is set
```

I want to know if there's some `$item->loadOptions()` method... or other native way to load options into an item

**UPDATE**

What I want to do: I want to load item object and use some native way to add its options to this loaded object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using next piece of code

```
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Option_Collection $options */
$options = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_item_option_collection');
$options->addItemFilter($item->getId());
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $item->addOption($option);
}
```

While I understand that it doesn't answer my question directly, I think there's just no method of loading options inside quote item.
So maybe someone will find the above piece of code useful.

Comment: do you still have no other solution? the cart can do it somehow

Comment: @Slayer Birden, looks like the core does it here: Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::_assignOptions, which is called towards the end of that class's _afterLoad(). 
It looks like it only happens on load of quote item collection, not an individual quote item. Further, it is a protected method.
Lastly, it is a very similar approach to the one you ended up using above.

Unfortunately for my needs, that happens after the core_collection_abstract_load_after event dispatch, so I need another way to observe that collection once the options are added.

Answer (score 2):

Let's me share what I can do for my case to get cart item option, here is my piece of code:

```
foreach ($item->getOptions() as $option) {
    if ($option->getCode() == 'info_buyRequest') {
        $values = unserialize($option->getValue()); // to array object
        // lookup custom option
        if ($values && array_key_exists('options', $values)) { 
            //
        }       
    }
}
```

As above code, I get all options of cart/quote item and lookup to find the code of **info_buyRequest** which stores the buying option of the item. My case, I was trying to look for the custom option of product that bought.

Note: You can check your item array data via: $item->getData() so that we can understand the structure of the data output.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am adding additional options to the quote item in an observer. These options are not saved on the product in the backend as they are created dynamically.

In the cart, you can then simply use:

```
$quoteItem = someMethodToGetYourQuoteItem();
$quoteItem->getBuyRequest()->getYouroption();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @pspahn! I didn't want to load additional options, in fact I wanted to load the options that already exist for this quote item in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well right now you instantiate a new quote item object without any data. If you would load an actual quote item, you can use the function `getOptions` to retrieve all the options associated with the quote item.

What is it you want to do exactly?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for pointing it out, I do actually load object, just forgot to add that part in code. Now it's updated. `$item->getOptions()` returns `null`

Comment: Are you sure then there are options linked to your quote item? (sales_flat_quote_item_option in db). I thought the quote item options would be automacally set on the quote item, if the quote item has options

Comment: I was under the same impression! That's why I created this question - because I still believe I might just overlooked something. To answer your question - yes, I'm sure there are options linked - at the least info_buyrequest will always exist